# one line of code using tab "\t" doesn't place at required position with c code

Tags: c, printf

Here is a program to print Roman Numeral values up to a
hundred everything works fine except for when `i==88`, on this line tab indents one extra set to stop. 
I sort of understand why that is 8 character. 
How can I fix that ? 
Thank you.

```
int main() {
    unsigned int i, tensDigit, singleUnit;

    printf( "Roman Numeral\t\t\t\tDecimal\n");

    for ( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) {
        tensDigit = i / 10;
        singleUnit = i % 10;

        switch ( tensDigit ) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("X");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("XX");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("XXX");
                break;            
            case 4:
                printf("XL");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("L");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("LX");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("LXX");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("LXXX");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("XC");
                break;
            case 10:
                printf("C");
                break;
            default: 
                break;
        }

        switch ( singleUnit ) {
            case 0:
                printf("\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("I\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("II\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("III\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("IV\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("V\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("VI\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("VII\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;
            case 8:                
                printf("VIII\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);                                
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("IX\t\t\t\t%d\n", i);
                break;            
        }
    }
    return 0; }
```

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0

Comment: `viii` is 4 characters, when you combine that with the characters from the 10s digit, you're going past a tab stop. that means you printf should have only **3** `\t` chars, not 4. e.g. `lxxxlxxx\t\t\t\t`

Comment: Note that the width of tab stops (and of specific characters) is a function of the output device, and perhaps of other factors as well.  It would be best to minimize your assumptions: either assume a fixed-pitch font and use spaces to align your columns, or assume tab stops can be set at convenient places and everywhere use a single tab between columns.

Comment: Form the entire roman number string in one buffer `rstring` and `printf("%-31s %d\n", rstring, i);`

Comment: suggest placing the parts of the roman numeral value into a character buffer. After all the parts are in the buffer, check the length of the buffer (perhaps with strlen) then have two printf statements, one for when the strlen is <8 and another for when the strlen is 8 or more.  Note: printf is expensive in code size.  so reducing the code to only 2 printf statements will dramatically shrink the code and will fix the logic problem